# Create and read a record in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working with Emeber.js framework; I've created an object like this:

```
myApp.user=Ember.Object.extend({
    name:null,
    state:false
});
```

I've also defined an Ember model this way:

```
myApp.Wuser = DS.Model.extend({
      nome: DS.attr('string'),
      user: DS.attr('mycustomtype') // i want put here a mycustom type (user)
});
```

The question is: how can I create a record? I've tried to write this:

```
myApp.Wuser.createRecord({nome:"aaa",user:myApp.user.create()});
```

but an error occurred; do you know how to create a record and how to read it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what was the error that occurred? also, i don't know if it's really a mistake, but normally, you start both app names and class names with a capital letter, i.e. `myApp.user=Ember.Object.extend({` should be `MyApp.User=Ember.Object.extend({`.

Answer (score 3):

You create a record on your store.

```
record = this.get('store').createRecord(MyApp.User, {name: 'Luke'})
```

To persist it to your server:

```
this.get('store').commit();
```

You can also do this for a transaction:

```
record = transaction.createRecord(MyApp.User, {name: 'Luke'})
```

Comment: shouldn't the other way work as well, though? [the corresponding ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/) seems to suggest that.

Comment: @FinnMacCool creating an Ember object is different from creating a new ember-data record. Creating ember-data records must go through the store (or transaction) so that the new record gets added to the store and can be looked up later, etc.